# How to read methods in a dll in C#?

Tags: c#

I am importing a library dll in a project and I want to test its methods. For example consider we have something like **myLib.dll** and I imported it and then I want to list methods for example get something like the following

```
int method1(int a, int b)
string method2(string name)
```

I want list them into an array in this format and in the next step I send some values like a, b, name and see output.
I find out it is possible to import **System.Reflection** call Assembly but not sure how can I retrieve all methods in the above format and then how can I pass variables and see outputs.

Comment: You get Assembly with Reflection. Then you loop over all types with [`asm.GetTypes()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes?view=net-6.0) call. Then you loop over MethodInfos of a type with [`type.GetMethods()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?view=net-6.0) call. As for calling, you can utilize [`methodInfo.Invoke()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke?view=netframework-1.1) call. Note that you have to analyze MethodInfo's signature in order to pass arguments correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two different things in your question.

If you have a library which you know won't change then you can write hard-coded calls to the classes and its methods - which you can find either via:

- Analyzing the code (Visual Studio will show you a simplified version if available),
- Decompiling the dll (using DotPeek or ILSpy), and looking at the methods.

Reflection is used when you want to know information during runtime (like [GetMethods()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?view=net-6.0) which you mentioned), when you can't just go and read the code and need to investigate the loaded assembly.

In this case I would recommend going for the hard-coded options mentioned above, since reflection sounds a bit overkill.